# PHP URL Rewriting for the link

Tags: php

I have delete link in a table for each row.
When I click on that link, I pass the id to a page which deletes that row using that id.
My last portion of my url looks like delete_row.php?id=5
Can I show only the delete_row.php with out showing the ?id=5

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function redirect(URL)
     {
       document.location="delete_row.php";
       return false;
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
?>
<table border="1">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:" onclick="return redirect('delete_row.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>');">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP part with file name delete_row.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The error which i am getting is 
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\MYXAMPP\delete_row.php on line 13

Comment: You should [not use GET for requests with side-effects](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.1.1).

Comment: you can try POST instead of GET

Comment: I suppose the real question is "why do you want to do this?"

Comment: This is a delete link, not a form. So I cant give GET or POST

Comment: @B Tyler: I need to do this because if we directly give the URL like http://localhost/delete_row.php?id=5 or http://localhost/delete_row.php?id=5 , then that records will get deleted. I need to avoid that

Comment: Even though it's not a form, it *is* a form -- technically speaking.  If you want to submit via a POST, you need to use a form... even if that form only consists of a link with JavaScript to make it call the form's `.submit()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
<a href="delete_row.php" onclick="this.href = this.href + '?id=5'">Delete</a>
```

You could also do this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function redirect(URL)
     {
       if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?'))
           document.location=URL;
       return false;
     }
</script>
<a href="javascript:" onclick="return redirect('delete_row.php?id=5');">Delete</a>
```

Comment: @Craig: Still i got this when i clicked delete link http://localhost/delete_row.php?id=5

Comment: My second solution might work for you. You will only need to have the script once because the onclick calls that function with the URL so multiple rows can all call the same function.

Comment: @Craig: Itz again showing that id when i clicked on delete button

Comment: What ID is it showing? Do you mean that after clicking the first solutions link it shows in the status bar?

Comment: @Craig: Ooops...Sorry. I forgot to replace the URL with some file name. Now it is not showing the ID

Comment: Also, with the redirect function, you can ask them if they want to delete.

Comment: Craig, There is some error in deletion, i wil edit my qn and can u please look into that

Comment: document.location="delete_row.php"; needs to be document.location=URL;

Answer (score 0):

How will the page then know what row to delete? You'll have to send some sort of identifier across to it. If you mean, after it's deleted, get the id to hide again, you can do that with a redirect by using:

header('Location: urlOfPageWithoutQueryString');

Comment: Craig's answer is clever, but of course, requires JS. You have to determine for yourself whether or not you're going to require JS. Alternatively you can do something with a <noscript></noscript> tag and add the JS supported link in... with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small form, with the "delete" button being a submit button.  Set the method to "post."  An example:

```
<form action="delete_row.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="row" value="5">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

In your PHP file, you can then use the `POST` values rather than `GET` values. This is more correct, as well -- `GET` actions should be idempotent (i.e. should have no effects except returning the requested information).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use GET for this kind of action at all as [GET is considered as being a *safe method*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.1):

> […] the convention has been established that the GET and
> HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
> other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".

Use a POST form instead where you can use a hidden form control for the ID:

```
<form action="delete_row.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete row">
</form>
```

Apart from the *safe method* reason, using POST instead of GET is also not that vulnerable against [Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). At that point you should also think about using so called CSRF tokens to further reducing the chances of successful CSRF attacks.